# Weird results when using an ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> in java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm getting weird problems in my android app and I think it may be linked to the behavior of the way the ArrayList works. Check the following code and please tell me if I'm correct or doing something wrong:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
tmp.add("test");
arr.add(tmp);
tmp.clear();
```

After the last line the contents of arr[0] is emptied. So does that mean that when adding one ArrayList to another it does it by reference?

So if I have the following method:

```
void addArray(ArrayList<String> arr) {
 group.add(arr); // group is ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>;
};
```

I must change it to:

```
void addArray(ArrayList<String> arr) {
 ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
 tmp.addAll(arr);
 group.add(tmp); // group is ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>;
};
```

to make sure that if I clear the incoming array somewhere else that nothing happens to the group array?

Comment: Yes, ArrayList (& all other collections) only stores references to objects, they do not clone or copy them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java there is no passing by value, every object is passed by reference. So in your case `arr[0]` and `tmp` are the same object and clearing it will result in `arr[0]` being cleared. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

As a quick answer to the second part of your question: you don't need to use the `tmp` `ArrayList` inside the `addArray` method. The argument of the `addArray` method is a **reference to the object, passed by value**. So changing it won't have **any** effect outside of the `addArray` method. Hope it's clear.

Comment: It would be more precise to say that references are passed by value: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm :)

Comment: Thanks. I assume if I were to call "tmp = new ArrayList<String>" instead of "tmp.clear()" the same thing would happen?

Comment: @stevovo, no the value of the reference is copied. Creating a new `ArrayList` and changing `tmp` does not change what has been added to the `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Bombe I added some changes to my question. Is that the best way of making sure that my arrays don't lose changes if the arrays inside are cleared?

Comment: I thought that would be obvious by now: copy the elements of an ArrayList to a new ArrayList. The way you do it above in the question seems to be correct but I’m sure that by now you have simply tested your method and found that it does what you want.

Comment: @Bombe yeah I was just wondering if that's the best way (memory / speed size). It does work though. Thanks

Comment: @stevovo, I've added an answer to the second part of your question, hope I've understood the issue properly.

Comment: @stevovo you shouldn’t worry about speed and memory consumption. a) Premature optimization is evil. Have you measured how your code performs at runtime? Is this your bottleneck? b) Choosing the right algorithm has a much larger impact on memory and speed. Do you really need to copy the ArrayList in question? Why is the ArrayList cleared after it is added to the other ArrayList? Maybe you should start at that point… are you trying to avoid creating new `ArrayList` objects by clearing and reusing one instance? If so, don’t. Just create a new one, your current problem will then simply disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, objects are not cloned when they're added to a collection.

Answer (score 0):

For objects Java always passes a copy of the reference value, so yes, the ArrayList you are clearing is the same as the one you added to the other ArrayList.